# How to access session variable in asp.net mvc using a javascript variable as a key?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to access a Session variable in ASP.NET MVC, but using a JavaScript variable as a key.

Here is an example in the success bloc of an ajax call :

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (idx, user) {

        var sessionUserId = '@Session[" ' + user.Id + ' "]'; //this doesn't seem to work

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Dont think you can do that... Java script runs on the client, session is kept on the server!

Comment: `@Session` is server side code. Javascript is client side code.

Comment: you can do this type of stuff in only cshtml files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a client side variable in server side code. You must post this client value to server (this is how [Client-Server Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) works basically).

May be you can get sessionId from a controller with using ajax, somethig like following;

**jquery**

```
$.get("SomeController/GetSessionId?userId=" + user.Id, function(result)
{
    var sessionUserId = result.SessionId;
});
```

**SomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult GetSessionId(string userId)
{
    return Json(new JsonResult { SessionId = Session[userId] });
}
```

Above code is just example how to achive what you want. There may be syntax errors.

OR

You can add your existing ajax result a field that named `SessionUserId` and define it's value at server side.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple  , try this.

```
var CompanyIdVal = '@Session["CompanyId"]';
```

here companyIdVal is javascript variable ^ where as companyId is the key of session variable.
I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

From your query, it seems that you need server side values on your client.
Since Javascript is run by your browser you won't be able to access "Session" object of the server.

Hence try the following alternates:
1. Make an ajax call to your server and get your Session value in response.
2. During login store your values in [sessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) service provided by the browser.

Thanks